# Free asp.net hosting for my college project

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am a student developing an asp.net website for my college project. I'd like to put it online for everyone to see. Are there any webhosts who allow me to host my web site for no cost?

Answer (score 3):

A [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=free%20.nethosting&aq=0l&aqi=g-l4g-lm1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=f72692c3f34d480a&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f72692c3f34d480a&ion=1&biw=1241&bih=885) show lots of hosts who claim to offer free .net hosting.

You could also host it yourself and use a dynamic DNS provider like [Zoneedit](http://www.zoneedit.com/) to handle the DNS for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here how i used to do it back in college. I used http://co.cc for domain name and http://freehostia.com for hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: also you can try http://110mb.com

Comment: both of these sites do not offer ASP.NET hosting

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.aspspider.com/ which is free.
It is good for trying out small projects.

Comment: it is no more providing the hosting services ...